# implimentation of online payment in iphone Apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've to implement online payment method in my app for selling some products like gift items. Which method will i use?in App purchase or paypal? Does paypal implemented apps accepted in appstore? plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are actual items that one would use outside the app. Like a book, or a DVD, and not something for use in the app, you need to use paypal or something similar. In app purchases are only meant to purchase added functionality or extra content within your app. See also [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html)

Apps with other payment methods than in app purchase are accepted, as long as the purchase is not added functionality or content for your app.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question lets understand two basic things:

1. You use Paypal implementation only and only when you purchase physical goods like gift items as you mention.
2. You use In App Purchase when you need to provide/ unlock some feature inside your application itself.

In your case as you mention you need to have transactions for gift items you have only one option i.e use online transaction APIs like Paypal.

Regarding your second question, Yes Paypal integrated apps are accepted in App Store. There are plenty of such apps already in the App Store